# Running my site on an old-fashioned phone emulated

Tags: website-design, mobile

Back in the day before iPhones were invented, different technologies (like xhtml/wap) were used to present pages. Now it seems that all new devices are HTML5 compatible.

I want to support the largest audience possible with my website.

I looked at a successful adsense publisher's mobile site wap.clickindia.com and the author uses xhtml. It renders fine on both my mobile smartphone and on my desktop computer.

Now my question is in regards to those who use cell phones to connect to the internet but aren't fully qualified as touch-screen smart phones. I'm referring to those that you press a series of buttons to connect to the internet, and on those phones, wifi was not an option. I remember owning one a few years back.

Here's a link to what the phone looks like (but you probably know anyways):

https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTIasqk9LErbqzJIaxJBgOAwpURWSrfwOs6OIkgfuV2exQbgySw9pJBpQ

I understand if this question must be closed for asking for external resources, but I'm curious as to if there is a utility or anything out there (even information) on how I can test my website on old-fashioned graphic phones without having to resort to buying one from a garage sale and paying hundreds of dollars for data on the device.

I ask this because I have used the w3c validator numerous of times to test things, but now I think its time to run tests on real devices so that I can see the same website content in the same format as what other users see (especially those from poorer countries).

I want to make sure my site is perfect for all regardless of device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Waste of time... because the time invested catering for the 00.001% could go to better use and making the better site for majority... its backwards thinking and I know in several threads I've said this, but unless you have dozens of developers improve your site for the majority. As you are in the entertainment industry delivering a rich experience should be your number 1 priority.

Comment: I already deliver a rich experience and it seems my adsense earnings follow it, but now I need to improve my mobile site and since most of the time I make $0 on mobile, it could very well mean I'm not making it compatible to 100% of the devices (both new and old)

Comment: Without offending, I've visited your site and there's not much user experience at all and room for so much improvement, most webmasters are constantly working on their UX nowadays, its huge SEO and traffic booster. If you want better conversions, better traffic then your UX has a long way to come. Comestics have a big impact too. UX is a huge topic and I highly recommend that you do some research into the field, people even do UX for a living. Sorry for closing the question, however you can get help using: Klondike WAP Browser, Yospace, Ericsson R380 Emulator, WinWAP, Nokia WAP simulator.

Comment: Compare http://www.tomorrowland.com/en/2015 & https://ultraeurope.com/gallery/ your notice comesticlly they are modern & the biggest UX factor is the images are cataloged, and popup when clicked... this is good UX... having to go from one page to another to checkout images is a HUGE killjoy. You can have purchase information in the popups. Your UX is dampened because your focusing far to much on squeezing every visitor for a click or purchase... UX is what drives traffic and conversions.

Comment: "especially those from poorer countries" - It's often the "poorer countries" that have the higher percentage of modern smartphone usage. They just don't have the laptop and desktop computers.

Comment: I have tried the Simon recommended UX approach of having the image change from one to the next without the entire viewing window clear first. I did not profit from that approach, Additionally I'm trying to give everyone a positive experience including those users with browsers without the ability to load javascript and/or CSS. An example of such browser is Arachne for Linux/DOS. I think I'm gonna use w3dk's comment as a hint. Now I think I'll change the HTML in my mobile site to comply more with xhtml (mobile profile)